# preg_replace to replace all instances of text in .php file

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm new here and a complete newbie. Sorry if this question is too basic, but i can't figure out the best way to do this.

I have quite a few .php files that contain various text placeholders. For example, in my .php file, I will have something like this:

I like xCity alot and want to live there.

or a link,

```
<a href="xcity_is_awesome.php">
```

I thought I could use some php code in the head of each page to do a preg_replace that would replace any instance of "xcity" or "xCity" with "mycity" or "Mycity" respectively.

I could currently get this to work:

```
< ?php
 $xCity = "Mycity"; ?>
```

as long as I replace all occurrences of "xCity" in the document with:

```
<?php echo $xCity ?>
```

I know there is a smarter way to do this, but like I said, I'm totally new.

Can anyone help me?

---

Here is what I am trying right now:

Using one of the examples below, I can't seem to get it to work.

I changed a couple of the variables from "xcity" to "{{xcity}}" in the document.

here is my code in the php file:

```
<?php
$xCITY = "MYCITY"; 
$xcity = "mycity";
$find    = array('{{xCITY}}','{{xcity}}');
$replace = array($xCity,$xcity);
$content = str_ireplace($find,$replace,$content);
?>
```

When I upload the file and preview it, the php doesn't change the text. I am sure I must be doing something wrong. :)

---

I am currently using the suggestion of SpencerJ (below):

```
<?php
 $xCity = "Calgary"; ?>
```

then using an echo statement to swap out the variable:

```
<?php echo $xCity ?>
```

I seem to run into a problem with php includes:

```
<?php include("<?php echo $xcity ?>_bottomlinks.php"); ?>
```

Now, I bet there is a an issue having multiple php "commands" with in each other like this. How would this be handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do a find-and-replace-in-project in most IDEs, to change xCity with `<?php echo $xCity; ?>`. For prepending `<?php $xCity = "Mycity"; ?>`, you could likely do the same in any IDE that also allows regex searches, by using `/^/s` (or something similar) although it would probably be easier to add it by hand in only the files that require it.

Instead of:

```
<div>My city is xCity and I think xCity is the coolest city in the world. Everyone should live in xCity!</div>
```

Use:

```
<?php $xCity = 'Calgary'; ?>
<div>My city is <?php echo $xCity; ?> and I think <?php echo $xCity; ?> is the coolest city in the world. Everyone should live in <?php echo $xCity; ?>!</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!Yeah, I was using BBedit to do a find/replace, but I am also using dreamweaver templates. When/If I update the template file, it will strip away any "variables" that i replaced. I know I could make each variable an "editable" region in the DW template... but i am sure there is a better way?

Comment: I don't have any experience with DreamWeaver templates, but it may be possible to insert your PHP code directly into the template, instead of your placeholder.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was doing. Just putting the code into the template :) But being new, I can't figure out the right way to write the code.

Comment: Without seeing what DW outputs, I don't think I'll be able to help much. It sounds like it may be escaping or stripping your PHP code, if it isn't showing up in your output properly.

Comment: Ah... i misunderstood. Yes, I can replace all instances of my xcity variable with <?php echo $xCity; ?>.

But is that the best way to go about this? I could have a quite a few instances of the echo in my html/php markup. Is that smart? (I inherited this site, so it's an existing site... not starting from scratch)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what `<?php echo $xCity; ?>` is made for :) I updated the post with an extremely basic example.

Comment: ok. I can totally get that to work then. From a web developer standpoint, is it better to do it this way or like user amigura suggested?

Comment: @amugirua's suggestion would load a PHP file that loads, replaces, and outputs an HTML file, resulting in two files for every page on your site (ignoring mod_rewrite). Using a variable and an echo is how PHP is intended to be used, and would ultimately result in far less headache down the road.

Comment: Perfect. That makes total sense. Thank you for the help! I am going to go to try an implement it now.

Comment: @SpenserJ yes i misunderstand the question as i saw preg_replace in the title.

Comment: That is probably because I don't know which php tag to use for this task. :/

Comment: SpenserJ, I also have php includes with city in the name. It seems the   php variable/echo won't respect the php include. I can update my question w/ an example...

Comment: @user2509823 An example would be great. Any included files will have access to the variables defined before they were included, and any code after the include will have access to variables defined before the include AND inside the included file.

Comment: I just updated the original question. Maybe I need to make a new question?

Comment: Don't think you need to in this case. `<?php include("<?php echo $xcity ?>_bottomlinks.php"); ?>` should be `<?php include($xcity . "_bottomlinks.php"); ?>` or `<?php include("$xcity_bottomlinks.php"); ?>`. Latter is making use of [variable expansion in double-quoted strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: <?php include($xcity . "_bottomlinks.php"); ?> works perfectly!

Comment: I can't tell you enough how much I appreciate the help, patience and education. THANK YOU!

Comment: My pleasure mate. Send me a message if you need a few more pointers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '<?php echo $xCity ?>';
echo str_replace('xCity', 'Mycity',$str);
```

**Output** -

```
<?php echo $Mycity ?>
```

Check - http://codepad.org/uVs6w3kH

Let me know if this is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [output control functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) :

```
<?php
$xCity = "Mycity"; 
ob_start(); // tell php you want it to buffer the output, not send it to the browser yet
?>
Text containing xCity
and maybe other stuff to replace
<?php
// now the page is complete, get the contents (and empty the output buffer)
$out = ob_get_clean();
// replace all the strings you want replaced
...
// and send the output to the browser
echo $out;
?>
```

The advantage is that you don't actually touch the pages themselves, you just wrap them in that output buffer.  But in the long run maybe using a proper php based template system will prove easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

If your going to use placeholders, make them unique to give them a boundary

EG: `<a href="{{xcity}}_is_awesome.php">`

This way you can protect variable like:

`$xcity="";` from being replaced.

```
<?php
$find    = array('{{xcity}}','{{mycity}}');
$replace = array($xcity,$mycity);

$content = str_ireplace($find,$replace,$content);
?>
```

Or a better way is to define actual PHP variables that you want to use in your script.

E.G within your file: `<a href="<?php echo $xcity ?>_is_awesome.php">` then whilst calling the file/view you can pass the values.

```
<?php 
//define your values
$data['xcity'] = "Some Value";
//load view and pass your variables to it
$content = loadContentView('TheFile', $data);


function loadContentView($view, $data=null){
    $path = './path/to/the/files/'.$view.'.php';

    if (file_exists($path) === false){
        die('Content view not found: '.$path);
    }

    /*Extract the $data passed to this function*/
    if($data !== null){
        extract($data);
    }

    ob_start();
    require($path);
    $return = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $return;
}
?>
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Using your first example, I can't seem to get it to work. <br />



I changed a couple of the variables from "xcity" to "{{xcity}}" in the document.

here is my code in the php file:

<?php
$xCITY = "MYCITY"; 
$xcity = "mycity";
$find    = array('{{xCITY}}','{{xcity}}');
$replace = array($xCity,$xcity);

$content = str_ireplace($find,$replace,$content);
?>

When I upload the file and preview it, the php doesn't change the text. I am sure I must be doing something wrong. :)

Comment: @user2509823 oh right, update your question with your updated code that you have tried.

Comment: ahh. yeah, i guess these comment sections don't allow for me to post snippets of code. updated the original question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$webpage = file_get_contents('mypage.html');

$findme = array('xcity','mycity');
$replace = array('mycity','Mycity');

$webpage = str_replace($findme,$replace,$webpage);

echo $webpage;
```

Comment: Do you know if this method slows down the loading of webpage? Well, slow it down in a way to impact load times for SEO?